# $\Bbb{Z}_px\subseteq\overline{\Bbb{Z}x}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, topological-groups, p-adic-number-theory

I'm studying $p$-adic integers and in the proof of the fact that closed subgroups of the additive group $\Bbb{Z}_p$ are ideals (see Robert's "A course in $p$-adic analysis", pp.23) I've found the following inclusion for $x\in \Bbb{Z}_p$:
$$\Bbb{Z}_px\subseteq\overline{\Bbb{Z}x}$$
where the overline denotes the closure of $\Bbb{Z}x$ in the $p$-adic integers.

What I know is that
$$\Bbb{Z}_p=\{\sum_{i\ge0}a_ip^i\mid a_i\in \Bbb{Z}\}$$
 and the topology is the one generated by the $p$-adic metric $d(x,y)=\frac{1}{p^{v(x-y)}}$, where $v(x-y)=\inf\{i\ge0\mid x_i\ne y_i\}$ is the $p$-adic order.

Can you help to figure out why this holds? Maybe it depends on the fact that It's difficult for me to understand what the closure looks like.

Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: While this is a much better written question, please do not delete [old questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3155503/bbbz-px-subseteq-overline-bbbzx?noredirect=1#comment6498429_3155503) and re-ask them. Instead, please edit the old version to improve it. That said, at this point, we might as well proceed with the current version, since it is a substantial improvement.

Comment: @jgon By re-ask do you mean edit the old one? I deleted the previous one because now I'm using the PC and I can be faster and more precise.

Comment: yes I meant that you could edit the old one to look as it does here in the new question. Regardless, I do appreciate this version of the question.

Comment: @jgon Ok, I'll keep in mind this fact in future. And I won't edit bad written questions via smartphone anymore

Comment: @jgon In the old question, you suggested that $\Bbb{Z}_p=\overline{\Bbb{Z}}$. I try to prove this using the topological definition of closure: $\overline{\Bbb{Z}}=\{x\in \Bbb{Z}_p\mid\forall B(x,p^{-n-1}), B(x,p^{-n-1})\cap \Bbb{Z}\}$. But any ball around a $p$- adic integer meets $\Bbb{Z}$  hence the conclusion, right?

Comment: @jgon If what I wrote in the previous comment is correct, then I get $\Bbb{Z}_px=\overline{\Bbb{Z}}x\subseteq\overline{\overline{\Bbb{Z}}x}$;

Comment: How can I prove that $\overline{\Bbb{Z}x}=\overline{\overline{\Bbb{Z}}x}$?

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the idea.

Let $a = \sum_{i\in\Bbb{N}} a_i p^i$ be a $p$-adic integer. Let $s_n = \sum_{i=0}^n a_ip^i$.

Observe that $s_n\in \Bbb{Z}$, and $(s_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}\to a$ in the $p$-adic topology, since $$a-s_n = \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty a_ip^i.$$

Then if $ax\in \Bbb{Z}_px$, $(s_nx)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}\to ax$, since multiplication is continuous. Thus $ax$ lies in the closure of $\Bbb{Z}x$. However $ax$ was an arbitrary element of $\Bbb{Z}_px$. Thus $\Bbb{Z}_px\subseteq \overline{\Bbb{Z}x}$.

**Side note**

If you don't yet know why multiplication is continuous, it's because if the first $n$ terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$ and $y_1$ and $y_2$ agree (thinking of them as power series), then the first $n$ terms of $x_1y_1$ and $x_2y_2$ agree. (*Proof.* Take both expressions mod $p^n$.)

Comment: Thanks for your very plain proof!